# Icecast local stream delay 3 seconds, what can i do?

Tags: networking, streaming, icecast

i am a newby on icecast an streaming.
My goal is o stream the music from my PC into my local Network.
I have installes the latest version of icecast and setup 192.168.1.2 as ip. this is the ip from my router. for testing i used RadioCaster. It works fine. But i have a delay about 3 Seconds to the original audio on my pc.

Is it possible to stream without a delay or only a very small delay? 
Please can anyone help me? Thank You.

Comment: has no one an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Icecast is the wrong tool for what you want.

It doesn't do reliable sub second delay streaming.

Comment: and what is the right tool for me?
I need a url like 192.168.1.2/stream1
and i want to stream all Audio from my windows pc. I made no podcast or something like that. i want to play audio on my windows pc and this should be streamed in my local wlan.